# Ler campos das tags no XML VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

Bom dia senhores,

Estou precisando ler um campo que se encontra dentro de uma tag no xml porém estou com dificuldades, precisaria fazer isso para montar um contador.

Meu projeto é ler o XML de uma venda e montar um cupom fiscal a partir disso, porém até o momento consegui apenas puxar um item da venda. Poderiam me ajudar ?

Estrutura XML, no caso eu precisaria ler o campo "nItem" que se encontra na tag "det", pois assim talvez eu conseguiria puxar todos os itens:

```
<det nItem="1">
    <prod>
        <cProd>7898577370182</cProd>
        <xProd>J.WATANABE/COUVE MANTE</xProd>
        <vItem>0.99</vItem>
    </prod>
</det>
<det nItem="2">
    <prod>
        <cProd>66396</cProd>
        <xProd>GRANEL/ALHO KG</xProd>
        <vItem>1.62</vItem>
    </prod>
</det>
```

Estrutura VB.NET

```
Dim produto As New BindingSource
produto.DataSource = ds
produto.DataMember = "prod"
Dim descricao As String = produto.Current("xProd").ToString()
Dim quantidade As String = produto.Current("cProd").ToString()
Dim valorprod As String = produto.Current("vProd").ToString()
```

Comment: É uma NF-e (Brasil)? Você tem um arquivo XML para ler do disco ou está em uma string na memória?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui fica um exemplo que pode ajudá-lo na solução:

```
Dim strXml As String =
    "<xml>
        <det nItem=""1"">
            <prod>
                <cProd>7898577370182</cProd>
                <xProd>J.WATANABE/COUVE MANTE</xProd>
                <vItem>0,99</vItem>
            </prod>
        </det>
        <det nItem=""2"">
            <prod>
                <cProd>66396</cProd>
                <xProd>GRANEL/ALHO KG</xProd>
                <vItem>1,62</vItem>
            </prod>
        </det>
    </xml>"
Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.LoadXml(strXml)

Dim xmlNodeList As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("det")
```

Depois de ter o objeto `xmlNodeList` preenchido, pode contar o número de ocorrências (se for isso que pretende):

```
Dim nodeCount As Integer = xmlNodeList.Count
```

Pode ainda percorrer cada nodo e fazer tratamento adicional (obter valor de propriedades, nodos filho, etc):

```
For Each node As XmlNode In xmlNodeList
    Dim value = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("nItem").Value

    Dim cProd As String = Convert.ToString(node("prod")("cProd").InnerText)
    Dim xProd As String = Convert.ToString(node("prod")("xProd").InnerText)
    Dim vItem As Double = Convert.ToDouble(node("prod")("vItem").InnerText)
Next
```